# How to mask a float mat in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mask, mat

I have a mat A of type `CV_32F` and a mask `M` with binary value 0 and 255. For example,

```
A = [0.1 0.2; 0.3 0.4]  
M = [1   0  ; 0   0  ]
```

I want to get the result of `A&B = [0.1, 0;0 0]`
While bitwise operation does not work on float mat. And I tried to convert the mask to `CV_32F` and then mask like the following, also not work.

```
M.convertTo(M, CV_32F);
A.copyTo(A, M);
```

So how to do it ?

Comment: Why do you need to convert the mask to `CV_32F`?

Comment: convert or not, neither works

Comment: Please provide your code and explain how doesn't it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because, as the doc of [**`Mat::copyTo`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto) says, **the function does not handle the case of a partial overlap between the source and the destination matrices**, while the source and the destination matrices are the same in your case.

You should save the result elsewhere, like

```
cv::Mat dst;
A.copyTo(dst, M);  // dst is what you want
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I was trying to use bitwise_and without success. Can you add that option?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
//to create mask
cv :: Mat floatMask
cv::threshold( someimage , floatMask , 0 , 1 , cv ::THRESH_BINARY );
floatMask.convertTo( floatMask , cv :: CV_32F);

// now to mask image 
floatImageToBeMasked = floatImageToBeMasked.mul ( floatMask ) ;
```